# TypeError: res is undefined when fetching data from dummyJson Api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, antd, fetch-api

- Hey guys, i need some assistance, am fetching from dummy Json Api, using fech method, however am experiencing an error "TypeError: res is undefined" yet i see that i have defined it .
- below is my useEffect hook which i use to get data.

```
import { getAllProducts } from "../API";

const Products = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getAllProducts()
            .then((res) => {
                setItems(res.data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, []);

    return (
        <List
            grid={{
                gutter: 16,
                xs: 1,
                sm: 2,
                md: 4,
                lg: 4,
                xl: 6,
                xxl: 3,
            }}
            dataSource={items}
            renderItem={(item) => (
                <List.Item>
                    <Card
                        key={item.id}
                        title={item.title}
                        cover={<Image src={item.thumbnail} />}
                    >
                    </Card>
                </List.Item>
            )}
        />
    );
}

export default Products;
```

- Below is where i have made the api call from

```
export const getAllProducts = () => {
    return (
        fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(console.log)
    )
}
```

- any help is highly appreciated. i think am missing something out to display data
- i can see in the console the products being fetched but when it comes to handling the response , i get res is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your last `.then` callback in `getAllProducts` calls `console.log` with the data and then returns the return value of `console.log`, which is `undefined`. This becomes the first argument of the `.then` callback in your `useEffect`. If you want to add logging, you still have to return the data so it can be accessed in the next `.then` handler in the chain.

```js
return fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        return res;
    });
```

In addition, the sample JSON returned has no `data` property. Its `products` property is an array though.

```js
setItems(res.products);
```

Comment: greate as you have said , i only needed to remove the last console.log and to change setItems(res.products);, thanks boss